# Why C# can't delivery array parameter?

Tags: c#, arrays

When i program a function with a DataRow array prarameter,it tips ")" expect with the row `private Dictionary<int,string> getViewColumnHeaderName(DataRow DR[]),`this is my code:

```
private Dictionary<int,string> getViewColumnHeaderName(DataRow DR[])
{
  System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>  dic=new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string> ();
  for(int i=0;i<DR[0].Table.Columns.Count;i++)
  {
    dic.Add(i,DR[0].Table.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString());
  }
  return dic;
}
```

When i tick the [],the program can run normal,but i just want to give the parameter a array ,how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `[]` next to parameter type, not parameter name:

```
private Dictionary<int,string> getViewColumnHeaderName(DataRow[] DR)
```

Answer (score 2):

change `DataRow DR[]` to `DataRow[] DR`

```
private Dictionary<int,string> getViewColumnHeaderName(DataRow[] DR)
```

Form [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> When declaring an array, the square brackets ([]) must come after the
>   type, not the identifier. Placing the brackets after the identifier is
>   not legal syntax in C#.

```
int[] table; // not int table[];
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already you should add `[]` to the parameter type not the parameter name.

This might appear a bit counterintuitive since you would use `DR[i]` to reference items in that array. However in a method signature you're defining what will be passed through the parameter not a specific object itself. And the item being passed is an array of `DataRow`, not an array of `DR`